# Recover non-relativistic density of state

Tags: special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, approximations, density-of-states

The density of state of a non-relativistic particle ($E = \hbar^2k^2/2m$) in 3D is:

$$\rho_{class}(E) = \dfrac{V}{4\pi^2}\left(\dfrac{2m}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}E^{1/2}.$$

The density of state of an ultra-relativistic particle ($E = \hbar kc$) in 3D is:

$$\rho_{ultra}(E) = \dfrac{V}{2\pi^2\hbar^3 c^3}E^{2}.$$

The density of state of a relativistic particle ($E = \sqrt{\hbar^2k^2c^2+m^2c^4}$) in 3D is:

$$\rho_{relat}(E) = \dfrac{V}{2\pi^2\hbar^3 c^3}E\sqrt{E^2-m^2c^4}.$$

As expected $\lim_{m\rightarrow 0}\rho_{relat}(E) = \rho_{ultra}(E)$, however, I cannot find a way to relate, the relativistic density of state to the classical one, like we could do for the energy of a particle in the small velocity limit.

Is there a limit in which $\lim_{?\rightarrow 0}\rho_{relat}(E)=\textrm{something}+\rho_{class}(E)$?

[source for the three formulae](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate classical dispersion relation that incorporates rest mass energy would be $E = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} +mc^2$, which would modify $\rho_{class}(E)$ to
\begin{equation}
\rho_{class}(E) = \frac{V}{4\pi^2} \big{(}\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\big{)}^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{E-mc^2}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

i.e. just shifting $E$ to $E-mc^2$. If the redefinition of $E$ is consistently implemented into your calculation, this shift will be irrelevant and drops out of the calculation.

It is now in the appropriate form to compare to the non-relativistic limit of $\rho_{relat}$.
Taking the limit, $E \rightarrow mc^2$, we have $E\approx mc^2$ and $\sqrt{E^2-m^2c^4} = \sqrt{E-mc^2}\sqrt{E+mc^2} \approx \sqrt{E-mc^2}\sqrt{2mc^2}$.
If we plug these in $\rho_{relat}$ you will arrive at the expression in $(1)$.

Answer (score 4):

The difficulty is that the definition of $E$ is changed. In the nonrelativistic case, $E$ is the kinetic energy only, while in the relativistic cases, $E$ is the total energy, including rest mass energy.

To obtain the nonrelativistic formula from the relativistic one, replace $E$ in the relativistic formula with $E+mc^2$ and then take the limit that $E\ll mc^2$.